# MySQL - Increase a Sum Value if the two Addends are the same

Tags: php, mysql

Struggling a few hours on a simple ***MySQL*** *update syntax*. *Table*'s `votesum` column is a sum of `vote1`+`vote2` column. If there are several `votesum` values that are equal to each other (*20 and 20 like the example below*), I need to increase the `votesum` by 1 for the  row that has the upper `vote1` value.

**Table**:

```
id|vote1|vote2|votesum
 1|10   |10   |20
 2|5    |15   |20
 3|2    |2    |4
 4|1    |1    |2
```

The ***MySQL*** *update syntax* I am looking for should check if maximum number of `votesum` is alone, or there are more equal votesum values. If there are two (or more) of them, then I need to increase value of `votesum`.

So after update table should look as follow:

```
id|vote1|vote2|votesum
 1|10   |10   |21
 2|5    |15   |20
 3|2    |2    |4
 4|1    |1    |2
 5|0    |2    |2
```

Remember that the top value of `votesum` are the ones that I needed to update. In the example above, `id=1` and `id=2` cannot be equal, but `id=4` and `id=5` can be equal, as I don't pay attention to those `votesum` values that isn't a top value.

Comment: The update created a new row. How comes?

Comment: @Marek I don't think the update created a new row. It is for example those rows should not be updated. read the last sentence.

Comment: @amaster507 I also read "So after update table ..." ;)

Comment: sometimes you just gotta read minds as to what the OP meant and not what he actually said... lol

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want:

<s>update `table` t1 join `table` t2 on t1.votesum = t2.votesum and t1.vote1 > t2.vote2 set t1.votesum = t1.votesum + 1 order by t1.votesum limit 1</s>

Comment: . . You can't use `order by` in an `update` with a `join` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

Comment: Too bad... then I don't think it's possible with one query. Subselects would result in another error.

Answer (score 0):

The following query uses variables to calculate the incremental value:

```
    select t.*,
           @inc := if(@votesum = votesum, @inc + 1 , 0) as inc,
           @votesum := votesum
    from t cross join
         (select @votesum := -1, @inc := 0) const
    order by votesum desc, vote1 asc;
```

This can be used in an `update` statement, using a `join`:

```
update t join
       (select t.*,
               @inc := if(@votesum = votesum, @inc + 1 , 0) as inc,
               @votesum := votesum
        from t cross join
             (select @votesum := -1, @inc := 0) const
        order by votesum desc, vote1 asc
       ) inc
       on t.id = inc.id and inc.inc > 0
    update t.votesum = t.votesum + inc.inc;
```